# Trying to access unlisted children of root node with phpSmug

Tags: php

I've modified the `example-oauth.php` file that comes with phpSmug to list the immediate children of the root node, but only public folders (those with at least one public album) and public albums are listed. I know my authorization (`Access=Full`) is correct, because when I try to list all user albums, I do get them all (code not shown). When I use the live example on the SmugMug site, I do get all immediate children of the root node. So, it seems the problem is within phpSmug, not with the SmugMug API itself. Also, I am replacing a Chrome App that also works as it should. (The Chrome App does not use phpSmug, of course.)

Any idea what's wrong and how I can fix it?

Here's my modified example. Lines that I added or changed are marked with the initials MJR. Note again that I didn't write most of this program, but only added and changed a few lines.

```
/* Last updated with phpSmug 4.0
 *
 * This example file shows you how to authenticate using OAuth and then display
 * the first 25 images in the first public gallery found of the authenticated
 * user's account.
 *
 * You'll want to set the following variables below:
 *
 * - $APIKey with one provided by SmugMug: http://www.smugmug.com/hack/apikeys
 * - $OAuthSecret with one provided when you obtained your API key
 * - $AppName with your application name, version and URL, eg
 *
 * The $AppName is NOT required, but it's encouraged as it will allow SmugMug to
 * diagnose any issues users may have with your application if they request help
 * on the SmugMug forums. A good format to use is "APP NAME/VER (URL)".
 *
 */

$APIKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';  // MJR -- my own data was entered
$OAuthSecret = 'YOUR_OAUTH_SECRET';  // MJR -- my own data was entered
$AppName = 'YOUR_APP_NAME/VER (URL)';
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>phpSmug OAuth Login Example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body { background-color: #fff; color: #444; font-family: sans-serif }
        div { width: 750px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; }
        img { border: 0;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="http://phpsmug.com"><img src="phpSmug-logo.svg" /></a>
        <h1>OAuth Login Example</h1>
<?php

try {
    $options = [
        'AppName' => $AppName,
        '_verbosity' => 1, # Reduce verbosity to reduce the amount of data in the response and to make using it easier.
        'OAuthSecret' => $OAuthSecret, # You need to pass your OAuthSecret in order to authenticate with OAuth.
        'verify' => false // MJR: Added because SSL certificates are not set up
    ];

    $client = new phpSmug\Client($APIKey, $options);

    // Perform the 3 step OAuth Authorisation process.
    // NOTE: This is a very simplified example that does NOT store the final token.
    // You will need to ensure your application does.
    if (!isset($_SESSION['SmugGalReqToken'])) {

        // Step 1: Get a request token using an optional callback URL back to ourselves
        $callback = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].':'.$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
        $request_token = $client->getRequestToken($callback);
        $_SESSION['SmugGalReqToken'] = serialize($request_token);

        // Step 2: Get the User to login to SmugMug and authorise this demo
        echo '<p>Click <a href="'.$client->getAuthorizeURL(['Access' => 'Full']).'"><strong>HERE</strong></a> to Authorize This Demo.</p>'; // MJR
        // Alternatively, automatically direct your visitor by commenting out the above line in favour of this:
        //header("Location:".$client->getAuthorizeURL());
    } else {
        $reqToken = unserialize($_SESSION['SmugGalReqToken']);
        unset($_SESSION['SmugGalReqToken']);

        // Step 3: Use the Request token obtained in step 1 to get an access token
        $client->setToken($reqToken['oauth_token'], $reqToken['oauth_token_secret']);
        $oauth_verifier = $_GET['oauth_verifier'];  // This comes back with the callback request.
        $token = $client->getAccessToken($oauth_verifier);  // The results of this call is what your application needs to store.
        // Get the username of the authenticated user
        $username = $client->get('!authuser')->User->NickName;

        // List top level folders and albums.  // MJR
        $user = $client->get('!authuser'); // MJR
        $root = $client->get($user->User->Uris->Node); // MJR
        $children = $client->get($root->Node->Uris->ChildNodes); // MJR
        foreach ($children->Node as $v) { // MJR
            echo "<br> $v->Type \"$v->Name\" $v->Uri"; // MJR
        } // MJR

    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "{$e->getMessage()} (Error Code: {$e->getCode()})";
}
?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I was using an API key that I got a few years ago. I created a new API key, and it works! Must be some weird state left over from before SmugMug went to API 2.

FYI: In the returned JSON, `ResponseLevel` is now set to `Full`. If this comes up for anyone else in the future, and you determine that the `ResponseLevel` is set to `Public`, that might be a clue that their problem is like mine.

Thanks for your help, lildude. You're a BIG dude in my book!

Comment: Great news!!! I didn't even think of an old API key being the issue as I discard and renew for all testing. Glad you worked it out. 

Answer (score 0):

Your changes should work, and do for me. One thing I did have to do was bump the count of nodes returned as `ChildNodes` returns only the first 10 nodes by default and my first private album is right at the very end.

Is your first private album/folder outside the first 10? If so, try changing your changes to:

```
// List top level folders and albums.  // MJR
$user = $client->get('!authuser'); // MJR
$root = $client->get($user->User->Uris->Node); // MJR
$children = $client->get($root->Node->Uris->ChildNodes, ['count' => 50]); // MJR
foreach ($children->Node as $v) { // MJR
    echo "<br> $v->Type \"$v->Name\" $v->Uri"; // MJR
} // MJR
```

You'll see I've added `['count' => 50]` to the options. You may need to increase this if you've got more than 50 albums/folders.

Alternatively, you can iterate through the pages using the info in `$children->Pages`.

Comment: Will try again later today. However, I have only 7 public top-level albums/folders, and only those 7 were returned Also, I did try various values for the `count` parameter. I also tried different values of the `start` parameter, to try to move past the first page, but that didn't return anything beyond the public albums/folders. Still, I will try again.

Comment: No joy. 7 public albums/folders, and those are all that show. I added an 8th public folder, and it shows. I have maybe 50 non-public folders, and they do not show. Here's something: The returned JSON has this field: "ResponseLevel"=> "Public". Do you get that? When I use the Live API on the SmugMug site, I do not see this. I tried setting responseLevel and ResponseLevel as input parameters, but that doesn't help. Besides, nowhere is responseLevel defined as a legal input parameter. Continuing to try more experiments...

Comment: Solved. See solution I just posted.